# Is there a bitcoin.conf option to disable the node from getting blocks?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I would like to use `bitcoin core` as a wallet only - to generate addresses and to sign transactions.

So I don't want it to download the blockchain.

Is there a `bitcoin.conf` setting for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `-h` option gives a list of all available options including

> -networkactive
>
> Enable all P2P network activity (default: 1). Can be changed by the setnetworkactive RPC command

I haven't tried setting that to zero.

Comment: I set it to zero with `networkactive=0`...the results `2021-08-15T11:30:54Z SetNetworkActive: false` and no blocks are being updated.

Comment: `2021-08-15T11:36:44Z Waiting for network to be reactivated before querying DNS seeds.`

Comment: Those messages are the sort of situation I would expect. Without downloading the blockchain, bitcoin-core cannot verify new blocks anyway. So the only use of this option might be to generate addresses and sign transactions - not to keep track of wallet balances. Maybe I misunderstood what you wanted?

Comment: No, it is exactly what I wanted. Keeping track of balance and a list of unspent transactions would probably have to be done by dumping the wallet and exporting all addresses and then checking on your full node.